# Custom log file not creating in magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.0

I am trying to create a custom log and print the info message on button click in Magento 2, I have extended the monolog/loggger method but the custom log file is not created. Someone can you say what is wrong with my code. Adding code for your reference.

CreateSourceButton.php is my PHP where I included logger
CreateSourceButton.php created inside the Block folder

di.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Search\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Engine">
    <arguments>
         <argument name="engines" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="coveo" xsi:type="string">Coveo</item>
         </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<preference for="Dss\CoveoSearch\Api\Service\TrackingInterface"
                type="Dss\CoveoSearch\Model\Service\Tracking" />
                <preference for="Dss\CoveoSearch\Api\Service\ConfigInterface"
                type="Dss\CoveoSearch\Model\Service\Config" />
                
<!--Configuration code for logger in magento 2-->
<!--Handler class reference-->
<type name="Dss\CoveoSearch\Logger\Handler">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<!--Logger class reference-->
<type name="Dss\CoveoSearch\Logger\Logger">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Coveolog</argument>
    <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Dss\CoveoSearch\Logger\Handler</item>
    </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

Logger.php

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Dss\CoveoSearch\Logger;
class Logger extends \Monolog\Logger
{
}
?>
```

Handler.php

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Dss\CoveoSearch\Logger;
use Monolog\Logger;
class Handler extends \Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base
{
    protected $loggerType = Logger::INFO;
    protected $fileName = '/var/log/coveo.log';
}
?>
```

CreateSourceButton.php

```php
<?php
namespace Dss\CoveoSearch\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
class CreateSourceButton extends Field
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_template = 'Dss_CoveoSearch::system/button.phtml';
    public function __construct(\Dss\CoveoSearch\Logger\Logger $logger,
    Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->_logger->info('I did something');
    }
    public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('coveo/system/CreateSource');
    }
    
    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
    
    public function getCustomUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('router/controller/action');
    }
    
    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button'
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => $this->getButtonId(),
                    'label' => __('Create'),
                    'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->doSomething()),
                ]
                );
            return $button->toHtml();
    }
    
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getButtonId()
    {
        return 'create_source';
    }
    public function executeApi(){
        $jsonEncodedData = json_encode(array(
            'sourceType' => 'PUSH',
            'name' => 'DSS-Coveo_M2-Integration-B2C-product-en_US',
            'sourceVisibility' => 'SHARED',
            'pushEnabled' => true
        ));
        $bearer = ' xxd540c63c-c809-4093-8d04-6733869b1a92';
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://platform.cloud.coveo.com/rest/organizations/dsspartnersorggrc3y48w/sources",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonEncodedData,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-type: application/json',
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $bearer
            )
        ));
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check first you can create log file by using zend code, I don't think it will work on onClick you'r code is correct I think.

Comment: I tried creating a log using the Zend and the log file is created on page load.

Comment: You have to give URL in it of Controller

Comment: @Ankit can i get any example?

Comment: Please May I know after adding Logger what you want to do, I think you want to execute you'r  executeApi() function right?

Comment: I have a custom button when i click the custom button i need to make a API call as well as print a custom log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122395/discussion-between-ajmalriyaz-and-ankit).

Answer (score 0):

please replace you'r code of onclick:

> 'onclick' => 'javascript:functionNameToBeCalled(); return false;',

Now write JS code in button.phtml and call ajax from it like:

> 

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'prototype'
], function ($j) {
```

> window.javascript:functionNameToBeCalled = function () { $j.ajax({});
> };

In ajax call controller, have log in it and call Custom APIs.

**NOTE** Close the brackets carefully, do not copy paste code completely.

Please let me know if you required anything.

Comment: the API is called when I refresh the page, but I have written the function to be called on button click.

Comment: Yes for that you have to fire ajax request, please follow the steps you will get it and it will not run on page refresh.

Comment: @Ajmalriyaz Please accept answer if you find solution satisfactory